# Formula to find Minimum date value of current month in date field across child objects

Tags: formula-field

I have a Date field which contains, across several child records:

`(2014-07-1,2014-07-5,2014-07-8,2014-07-9,2014-08-1,2014-08-5,2014-08-8........)`, now in these values I want to get the `current month(August) minimum date value`, that is:
 `2014-08-1`.

How to do this in Formula field?

Comment: how are these date values stored ? comma separated in a text field ? or these are values from a single date field across multiple records ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna No these are not comma separated values,these are single date field values.

Comment: You want to save in the parent the minimum month from a related list of childObject.dateField__c ?  If yes, please reword your question

Comment: @crop1645 Yes i want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a formula that could reliably do this, but it could certainly be done with an Apex trigger.

Although it seems like it would be worth separating these date entries into a related custom object & then simply using a Rollup (min) field to find the lowest value in the current month.

Comment: Here's the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US), explaining the various functions which you can use to define roll-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I misread the question, I think you would need a trigger to do this, since I don't believe rollup filters let you use relative dates: see idea exchange idea here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrUAAA0

Answer (score 0):

you can do it just using formula.
in your child obj, create a number type formula to calc the result, the main part is use your date field  minus first date of the month :
DATEVALUE(Your-Date-Field) - DATE( YEAR(DATEVALUE( $System.OriginDateTime )) , MONTH(DATEVALUE( $System.OriginDateTime )) ,1)
and use if else to get result only when the result greater than 0.

then in the parent object, create a rollup summary for store the minus value,
then create an formula to calc the min date, use first date of the month plus the minus value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
date.today().toStartOfMonth()
```